# webclient does not recognize the text of the page C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem with the web client does not recognize the contents of the web.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    
    try
    {
        if (!webClient.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/SUVh3TP1").Contains("dasda"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Working!");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `webClient` is successfully downloading that URL and reading the string that's there ("dasda"). Because you have a `!` at the start of your if condition, when the `.Contains()` evaluates to `true`, the expression in the `if` evaluates to `false` and the `MessageBox.Show()` is skipped.